# FileNotFoundError when writing pickle file in numpy.save

Tags: python, pickle, python-3.7

I'm seeing a confusing intermittent error.  Sometimes when I call `np.save` I'm getting `FileNotFoundError`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/leo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 536, in save
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/leo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 629, in write_array
    pickle.dump(array, fp, protocol=2, **pickle_kwargs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "/home/leo/dev/vizproc/embed.py", line 59, in save
    np.save(filename, obj)
  File "/home/leo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 539, in save
    fid.close()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

The directory it's writing to definitely exists, and the object is a dictionary with a mix of `[str]` and `np.ndarray`, so it's getting pickled on the way out.  Looking at the numpy source, it seems that it's trying and failing to close the file it had opened for writing:

```
    own_fid = False
    if hasattr(file, 'read'):
        fid = file
    else:
        file = os_fspath(file)
        if not file.endswith('.npy'):
            file = file + '.npy'
        fid = open(file, "wb")
        own_fid = True

    if sys.version_info[0] >= 3:
        pickle_kwargs = dict(fix_imports=fix_imports)
    else:
        # Nothing to do on Python 2
        pickle_kwargs = None

    try:
        arr = np.asanyarray(arr)
        format.write_array(fid, arr, allow_pickle=allow_pickle,
                           pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
    finally:
        if own_fid:
            fid.close()   # <=- FileNotFoundError
```

and inside the `format.write_array(...)` call is really just some type checking and then `pickle.dump(arr, fid, protocol=2, **pickle_kwargs)` which is also raising `FileNotFoundError`.

I'm using Numpy: 1.16.3, Python: 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38) [GCC 7.3.0] on Ubuntu 18.04.

I'm trying to reason through what kind of race condition could cause this, or why else it might be happening.  Is it that the file is getting opened by this process, but then another process erases the file before the writing happens?  Seems reasonable, but then this should repro the failure, which it doesn't:

```
fid = open("testfile", "wb")
os.unlink("testfile")
pickle.dump({'obj':'test'}, fid, protocol=2)  # no error
fid.close()  # no error
```

Also, after the error gets raised, there's a zero-byte file on the disk.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Is the file on a network share or removable drive?  Having the device containing it disappear during the process might cause an error like this.

Comment: The drive is definitely not getting unplugged.  I have a process continuously updating these files, and it works sometimes, fails sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the root cause of this was a hardware problem or something deep in the disk system.  Frustratingly, the OS wasn't logging any error messages.  A bunch of details [in this github issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/14626) including a simpler repro case, in case anybody wants to dive in.  Key points: it only happened on USB-attached disks, and only if the path had a symlink in it.